# Dynamic Windows Forms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am creating a `TextBox` dynamically and adding that in a TabPage which is itself also dynamically created.

But the problem is, the `TextBox` is not showing text formatting correcly.

For example: \t and \n are not reflected at all.

I have already set property `Multiline` to True. But again no improvement.

What to check for?

Comment: could you provide a sample of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you dynamically create the TextBox, make sure you set its MultiLine property to `true` (the default is `false`).  And if you want multiline text, you have to use `\r\n` - just `\n` won't do it.  `\t` puts a `Tab` in correctly - maybe you're looking for something else?